# How do I use dex2jar to reverse multiple dex files

Tags: java, android, jar, dex, dex2jar

I know that when the apk file is decompressed and there is only one dex file,

d2j-dex2jar.bat classes.dex will get the correct jar file,

But with classes.dex, classes2.dex, classes3.dex files, what should I do to get the correct jar?

Comment: Decode them all :P

Comment: Is dex2jar still maintained? I would try alternatives like [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx), it directly converts apk/dex -> Java Source.

Answer (score 0):

download the latest version of dex2jar (grater than 2.1 version), then use command `dex2jar [test].apk` directly, then it will reverse all dex files into jar file.